# Monero wallet issue with multiple accounts

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, monero-wallet-cli, daemon, mymonero

I have a monero wallet with more than 10 accounts. When I transfer coins from one account to another, unlocked balance does not refreshed for more than a hour.

After that, I entered `rescan_bc` and it shows only few accounts. When I tried to restore it, it shows again only few accounts, but all the transaction are in the wallet. Remaining account and balance are gone.

Please, can you help me with this issue?

Comment: How many addresses total were in your wallet and did you perform a recover from seed? Reason I ask is there is an issue with restoring wallets with high number of addresses.

Comment: almost 12000 account

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/10704/accounts-got-deleted-from-the-wallet

Comment: Thanks. Its the same scenario from above question but i created account not a sub address. will that command help me to restore account and balance in wallet

Comment: Yes it's the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need 10 confirmations to get balance becomes unlocked, but you should be able to see a new balance (not unlocked) once the first confirmation gets in.

Apart from that, you always need to have your wallet fully synced with the **Monero** blockchain to get it updated with the newest transactions.

Comment: my wallet is fully sync. but account address with balance is not shown.