# Accounts got deleted from the wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I have a wallet with more than 10,000 accounts in it. I have tried to send some amount from one address to another address within the wallet but the amount sits in the sender's ledger balance for a long time so I ran `rescan_bc` from the wallet-cli. after rescan I can see only 1717 accounts in my wallet the rest of the accounts got deleted from my wallet. I try restore the wallet using the seed but it didn't help. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Did those accounts see any activity in the past (i.e. received a transaction)? If not, a `rescan_bc` will not pick them up.

Comment: Also, did you at some point restore from seed? I ask because there is a limit to the amount of addresses/created scanned on restore. You don't loose anything and IIRC there is a command to recreate.

Comment: Does 'accounts' mean 'addresses'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accounts are never "deleted". The wallet does, however, need to precompute some elliptic curve points for all possible accounts and subaddresses that it will search for incoming funds at. By default, the wallet will not look ahead more than 50 accounts at a time, and will not look ahead more than 200 subaddresses at a time, unless it sees activity at those subaddresses.

You can start the `monero-cli-wallet` with the option `--subaddress-lookahead MAJOR:MINOR` where `MAJOR` is the number of accounts to look ahead, and `MINOR` is the number of subaddresses to look ahead.

I assume that you misspoke when you said that you had 10,000 accounts, and meant that you had 10,000 subaddresses all within the same account. Therefore, use the option `--subaddress-lookahead 50:10000` and then type `rescan_bc` when you're inside the wallet.

Note that looking ahead 50:10000 means precomputing 500,000 elliptic curve points, because 10,000 subaddresses will be precomputed for each of the 50 accounts. Therefore, expect the operation to start the wallet to take a few minutes.

Comment: @knaccc I mean accounts only, I have more than 10000 accounts and in wallet-cli I can see only 1000 accounts. The rest of the accounts has balance in it. I was able to access those accounts balances through wallet-rpc but suddenly one day when I try to access the balance for account after 1000 index the rpc returns 0 balance

Comment: @knaccc I got all my accounts and balances back, as you suggested I have restored the wallet using this command `./monero-wallet-cli --restote-deterministic-wallet --subaddress-lookahead 15000:1` Thank you very much for your help.